# ASP.Net Application Self Updating

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to get an existing asp.net web application to update from within itself.  We have alot of different clients using the application all with different connection strings so it can't be just a simple deploy.

I am currently deploying to filesystem, zipping up and uploading (without web.config) and the client downloads and extracts accordingly.  I don't like this as it requires being on the server or creating a share to the application.

So I created a signalR hub in the application which downloads the file and unzips it.  This works but the page stops getting info back from the hub when it starts extracting obviously because the application is being restarted I guess.

Is there a way to get this to work within the application and report on it's progress, I don't want to use anything external if I can help it I simply want to update it like you would update Wordpress from within itself for example.

EDIT: Just want to point out I used a hub so I could show live progress of percent downloaded of the zipped file and progress of extraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite trying several things I couldn't get this to work so instead I created a console application with a configuration file amended for each client that they can run themselves or even add as a scheduled task which seems to be working out pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

We have a custom system based on this idea.

The trick is to have a separate application for updates. The application exposes a web service which accepts signed requests containing application deployment files. Then, requests are stored in a local queue and processed by a service which:

1. Stops the app pool
2. Unzips the new version
3. Rewrites config template files using locally stored properties
4. Starts the app pool and pings back in case of any issues

What we need then in our main office is a new version of the app which is then distibuted to all locations around (around 20 at the moment). No big issues.

The distribution subsystem has been developed internally years ago and is based on .net just because we haven't found anything which would fulfill our requirements at that time. Since then we haven't tried to search for any third-party tools which would do the same.

Comment: I don't want to use a seperate application but thank you.  Also I need the client to request the update as we may not have access to push the updates to them as some restrict external access.

Comment: As soon as you update application files, it unconditionally restarts. I think this makes self-updating just impossible.